# Navbar Section Highlighting

Tags: html, jquery, css

Recently I tried adding functionality to a website I am making by making the current section the user is on appear as "highlighted" in the navbar. In order to do this, I added this JQuery script to my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '.navbar-end a', function() {
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        });
</script>
```

This function determines which section of the navbar was clicked and adds the class "active" to the specific anchor tag. The class "active" is styled with a different color so that it appears different from the other navbar elements.

My Navbar:

```
<div class="hero-head">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-menu">
                <div class="navbar-end">
                    <a href="{{ url_for('welcome') }}" class="active">
                        Home
                    </a>
                    {% if not current_user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}" class="navbar-item">
                        Login
                    </a>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('signup') }}" class="navbar-item">
                        Sign Up
                    </a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" class="navbar-item">
                        My Tasks
                    </a>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}" class="navbar-item">
                        Logout
                    </a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    color: #b2b1b1;  
    font-family: Lato;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 3px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
} 
.active {
    color: #19dafa !important; 
}
```

Now I will describe the issue I am facing. After making these changes, when I click on a tab on the Navbar on my site, it only momentarily changes to the color specified by the active class. For a split second the color is #19dafa, but then it changes back to #b2b1b1 immediately after (without me clicking on a different Navbar section). This led me to believe that the color was immediately getting overwritten by another style. After trying to debug around this claim, I was unable to find any fixes. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: When I copy your code into [a codepen](https://codepen.io/bobsfriend/pen/VwKNaNB), It workes just fine. I would try to clear your browser's cache.

Comment: Hmm, after emptying cache and hard reloading, the issue still occurs. I actually didn't paste my entire CSS file, just the part I thought was relevant. Also, my Navbar is actually nested in multiple divs. I wonder if the portion of code I presented here doesn't have any issues, but in my code (the entire thing) the issue is still present. Could this be possible? I have update the files accordingly just in case. Edit: After pasting my entire code into the Codepen, it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I am still confused in regards to one thing. Why does the Navbar highlighting functionality I implemented only work on CodePen? I cleared the cache for the port I am using on multiple browsers and tried seeing if the functionality worked on those browsers, but they didn't. What could be causing this and is there any way to fix this?

Comment: does it work in the codepen?

Comment: Yes, it does work in the codepen.

Comment: that means that there is some kind of problem with the rest of your code.

Comment: Hmm, but I pasted my entire code into the Codepen and it worked. The exact same code just doesn't have the navbar highlighting functionality in the browser.

Comment: yea, I don't know what to do then

Comment: Will the links lead to different HTML files or just to part of the same page?

Comment: They lead to different HTML files.

Comment: In my code I use a code block so that each page inherits the Navbar (so I don't have code for the Navbar on each page). I wonder if after I click the tab and the active class is added to the current Navbar item, the page inherits the old Navbar code resulting in the home page being highlighted still and not the current page...

Comment: ^That was indeed the issue. I solved it by adding if statements to check the url of the current page and then adding the class to the respective element.

Comment: glad you figured it out